# CKEDITOR's insertHtml not working except in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have a function called fillFields and calling `CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.insertHtml('<p>My stuff</p>');` within that will not work but the following will:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.insertHtml('<p>My stuff</p>');
    }, 1);
```

Any clues as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to enter data in CKEditor after you initialize it, you have to wait until CKEditor instance is loaded and ready for interaction. Use the [instanceReady](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady) event:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    evt.editor.insertHtml('<p>My stuff</p>');
});
```

Comment: That's not the case, but I did determine what the problem was from your answer. I was calling setData to reset the editor before and since it is asynchronous it would end up called after insertHtml thus resetting it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stemmed from resetting the editor before inserting html by calling `setData` and not using the callback to then call `insertHtml` which led to `setData` resetting my editor after having inserted the html.